# Where should business logic be placed in a controller/model/view project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oop, asp.net-mvc-5

I am wondering what the best practice is for creating a complex view and model.

I have been reading that you are suppose to handle business logic in the model, and only use the controllers for handling the request and view results `json`, `string`, etc. Is this correct?

I came across another article that said business logic is suppose to be in the controller, and domain logic is in the model.

Also, is it best practice to use constructors, or can this cause issues like having to extend the binder for it.

Any advice, and a reference to a complex design implementation of a model view and controller would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, I like to separate all the layers to separate projects and make it MVVM way

1. Bus logic, would be best to put in service/domain layer
2. Controllers are used to get/parse/send request/response to view
3. Models, a model for your view (not your business model), could have the same information as your model or more/less.

Orchard is a good example of mvc/ piranha/ nopcommerce.

Some old adopters put all business logic in model, some others put them in controllers, which I think is not clean.

Comment: I think this explains it well. Thanks for both responses.

Comment: Thanks for the source reference btw. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the business logic will be placed in a separate project all by itself, not knowing (no reference) about the web project or the data access (also separate) projects.

Comment: Didn't mension that we are also using Entity Framework. I am just wiondering though about this. Like using constructor and default constructors, and inheritance my models, is a good idea for my situation, or is a bad practice. Just seemed like the best way to handle this particular view section. I want to stomp on bad habits before they become habits. I just switched to this in our company, so am learning it.

Comment: In large projects you should have at least: 1. database project (tables, views, etc), 2. business layer project (you Entity framework entities, + business logic), 3. web project (MVC). Since you are using EF you do not need a separate data access project (IMO)...

Comment: I disagree slightly. Even if you're using EF, you should still use a class library for your domain layer. You may only have one project that needs to work with your entities *right now*, but the minute you need a second project to be able to interact with them, you'll be kicking yourself for days.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that all business logic should be handled by another application layer

Microsoft has its own definition of mvvm which is useful once we are developing on their platform.

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx

I`ve been using [CSLA](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/) + MVVM + [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it has proved itself very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

About MVC (not MVVM)

I prefer to put domain logic in the model for a couple of reasons.

- The model should have no UI code in it and should be easier to test. Whenever possible, I like to have a fully working model before writing any UI code. The controller can trust that the model is doing the right thing and just deal with UI concerns and redirecting stuff.
- If you put domain logic in a controller, it's not as easy to share between different applications or even controllers!